# javascript inside html-erb files issue

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I ma trying to understand why this javascript inside my erb file is not working

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
    var tmp= "<%=j  render :partial  => "layouts/alert_error_message", :object=>@campaign %>";
<% end  %>
```

I get this message

```
compile error
/var/www/gitorious/app/views/campaigns/new.html.erb:32: syntax error, unexpected ')'
...r.concat(( javascript_tag do ).to_s); @output_buffer.concat ...
/var/www/gitorious/app/views/campaigns/new.html.erb:38: syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting ')'
```

When I use instead `<% javascript_tag do %>`, the render method is correctly processed but the tmp variable is not set in my javascript (`console.log(tmp)` returns `undefined`)

Edit : I wrapped the render method with `escape_javascript` and it worked but I still don't undestand why it is only working when I use `<% javascript_tag do %>`. Is it not suppose to work with `<%= javascript_tag do %>` ?

Comment: It looks like you have an extra `)` in your `new.html.erb`line 32.

Comment: line 32 corresponds to "<%= javascript_tag do %>"

Comment: So maybe in your partial `layouts/alert_error_message` there's an extra `)`

Comment: no if I take var tmp="hello", I have the same message...

Comment: @LuísRamalho I have edited my post if you're interested